# How to connect two monitors to a macbook pro?

Tags: mac, display, work-environment

I have a 13" macbook pro, and I need much more space right now, so I decided to buy two smaller monitors. ([these from LG](http://www.lg.com/uk/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=W2253V-PF&initialTab=warranty&targetPage=support-product-profile)).

But I don't really know how will I connect them. I've seen some products like this [Diamond BVU195](http://www.diamondmm.com/BVU195.php), but it's not currently in stores in my country.

I've found these

- [Equip 128450 USB 2.0 Display Adapter](http://www.pcland.hu/shop+Equip-128450-USB-2-0-Display-atalakito--USB-rol-VGA--DVI--HDMI-re_109285_3420887)
- [DELOCK USB 2.0 to DVI/VGA/HDMI Adapter](http://www.pcland.hu/shop+DELOCK-USB-2-0-to-DVI---VGA---HDMI-Adapter-DL61787_97231_342)

The second one looks pretty cool, but it says that Windows is a system requirement or what, so I'm not sure if it will work with mac os x?

So how did you connected multiple monitors to you mac, and are these adapters the best choices, if yes then is there an OS independent one?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably NOT the best option, but it does work.  I have a late 2011 15" MBP.

For my main display, I used the [Apple DisplayPort adapter to DualLink-DVI](http://%28http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A%29)

For the 2nd display, I am using the [StarTech USB2DVIPro](http://ca.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/Professional-USB-DVI-External-Dual-or-Multi-Monitor-Video-Adapter~USB2DVIPRO)

The USBtoDVI adapter is a bit laggy, but I only use it for email.

There are other options available, like the Matrox DualHeadToGo (or TrippleHeadToGo).  However, after looking at the price and functionality I went this route.

The ultimate solution would be 2 ThunderBolt Apple 27" displays, but that is not in my budget.

Sean...

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [Diamond BVU195 HD USB Display Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002GHBW4S).

Comment: your answer is a bit short. Perhaps you can add some text on how to use/experience of the adapter.

Comment: It's a plug and play device. An alternate one is: http://www.amazon.com/Kensington-Universal-Multi-Display-Adapter-Black/dp/B002F9NSMQ/ref=cm_cmu_pg__header

Comment: monitors over usb are probably laggy